# Bootstrap Column Grid With Selected Borders

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

I'm using Bootstrap to display a row of columns. Each column has a background image, a border and there is no gap between them. When the list has more than one column, the neighbour column borders create an undesired effect that seem like the borders have different widths. Here's what happens:
[image: Borders with different widths]

This is what i need to achieve:
[image: What i need to have]

My HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-4 product" style="background: url(../img/product/prod_1.jpg) center;">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="overlay">                   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 product" style="background: url(../img/product/prod_2.jpg) center;">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="overlay">                   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- (...) -->
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS/SCSS:

```
.product
{
    //how to resolve the border issue?
    border:2px solid $main-color-light;

    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    .container
    {       
    }
}
```

How can i achieve this?

**Important Note: The row can have an undetermined number of products.**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question has changed since my first attempt so here's a new, much simpler solution.

First, I believe you're using the Bootstrap grid incorrectly. The `.container` class is already used in Bootstrap so you should rename your inner elements to a new class. In the example below I've used the `.inner` class.

Now for the magic, in your case you want a border of 2px. To make this consistent around every element give each element a `margin: 0 -2px -2px 0;` This will cause the elements border to overlap on the right and bottom sides, achieving the effect you want.

This will work with any number of elements, independent of how many elements you put in a row or how many elements there are total.

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
}

.container {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.product {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0 -2px -2px 0;
}

.inner {
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 product" style="background: url(http://placehold.it/300x300) center;">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="overlay">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 product" style="background: url(http://placehold.it/300x300) center;">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="overlay">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 product" style="background: url(http://placehold.it/300x300) center;">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="overlay">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 product" style="background: url(http://placehold.it/300x300) center;">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="overlay">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 product" style="background: url(http://placehold.it/300x300) center;">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="overlay">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 product" style="background: url(http://placehold.it/300x300) center;">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="overlay">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 product" style="background: url(http://placehold.it/300x300) center;">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="overlay">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 product" style="background: url(http://placehold.it/300x300) center;">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="overlay">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 product" style="background: url(http://placehold.it/300x300) center;">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="overlay">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 product" style="background: url(http://placehold.it/300x300) center;">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="overlay">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: spot on! that did the magic :) thx for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: Great. A small side-effect of this method is the entire row will be a few pix off to the left. With 4 elements per row the negative margin will cause the entire row to shift 8px to the left. You can compensate for this by adding a wrapper element with a `margin-left`. Something to keep in mind for if you're wondering why it's not centered.

Comment: that's exactly what i did :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this, the general idea is to remove the extra border width on a few select sides of some elements. Here's an example for your setup where you have rows of 3 elements. This setup will work on rows of any number of elements though, the only requirement is target the elements in the last row to reapply the bottom border to those elements.

Three things happening here:

1. Add the 2px border to the top, right and left (but not the bottom) of all elements.
2. Add a border of 2px to the bottom of the elements only in the last row (`.row:nth-of-type(2) .product`).
3. Remove the right-side border all but the last element (`.product:not(:last-child)`).

```css
.product {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.product:not(:last-child) {
  border-right-width: 0px;
}
// Should be `.row:last-child .product` but there's a bug with SO
.row:nth-of-type(2) .product {
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
}
.container {
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 product" style="background: url(http://placehold.it/300x300) center;">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="overlay">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 product" style="background: url(http://placehold.it/300x300) center;">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="overlay">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 product" style="background: url(http://placehold.it/300x300) center;">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="overlay">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 product" style="background: url(http://placehold.it/300x300) center;">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="overlay">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 product" style="background: url(http://placehold.it/300x300) center;">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="overlay">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 product" style="background: url(http://placehold.it/300x300) center;">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="overlay">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** There is a [bug with the Stackoverflow snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285347/snippet-css-last-child-bug) that prevents `:last-child` from working. The line `.row:nth-of-type(2) .product` should be `.row:last-child .product`.

Comment: thanks for your solution, but my issue is that the row can contain an undetermined number of products. How can your solution be applied to this issue?

Comment: this happens when a row has more than 3 products: http://imgur.com/jTvhddi

Comment: Looks like you didn't change the `col-` classes. If you want 4 columns you would need to change the classes to `col-md-3`. Like [this].(http://codepen.io/brettdewoody/pen/zNKdxj)

Comment: the idea is for the layout to be responsive and the same row containing 1 or more products. here's what i what to do: http://imgur.com/BOKcl3z